# Creating a NodeJS runnable single javascript file from Clojurescript

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, clojurescript

Using Lumo and the files mentioned below I am able to run `$ node main.js` and *presto!* "Hello world!". This is great but there are drawbacks to using Lumo, and I would like to know if this is possible with the *cljs.jar*.

How can I create a single javascript file from clojurescript using the ClojureScript Compiler (cljs.jar) that can be ran by NodeJs.

#### core.cljs

```
(ns hello-world.core
  (:require [cljs.nodejs :as nodejs]))
(nodejs/enable-util-print!)
(defn -main [& args]
  (println "Hello world!"))
(set! *main-cli-fn* -main)
```

#### node.cljs

```
(require '[lumo.build.api :as b])
(b/build "src"
  {:main 'hello-world.core
   :output-to "main.js"
   :optimizations :advanced
   :target :nodejs})
```

The goal is to have a single file that is all inclusive with no import/require of external files.

**Why do I want this?**
There are many websites that have developer challenges for creating and/or enhancing algorithms. The problem is that most of these sites do not all you to use clojure, nor clojurescript. But they do let you use javascript.

These sites usually allow you to use Java as well...so if there is a another way perhaps get an export of a "java" file, not a Class file, that would also work. I doubt thats possible but figured I'd ask.

Comment: What is not working in your current setup? Doesn't build with your `node.cljs` generate a single javascript file that can be run with `node`?

Comment: Oh, you are using `lumo.build.api`. I think you can do the same with [`cljs.build.api`](https://clojurescript.org/guides/quick-start#running-clojurescript-on-node.js).

Comment: All my attempts to generate a single file that can be executed by NodeJs failed. They included import statements. The key is not to import anything, I would like to have an all inclusive file. I updated the post to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**build.clj**

```
(require 'cljs.build.api)
(cljs.build.api/build "src" {:output-to "main.js"
                             :main 'hello-world.core
                             :target :nodejs
                             :optimizations :advanced})
```

**build command**

```
  java -cp cljs.jar:src clojure.main build.clj
```

Comment: From my testing this includes the google closure functions for imports. I've updated the comment with clarifications. I'd like to generate a single javascript file that contains all required libraries.

Comment: If you add `:optimizations :advanced` or :simple, it will bundle all deps into one file.

Comment: Thank you! IDK where I went astray but your solution worked.

    (require 'cljs.build.api)
    (cljs.build.api/build "src"
      {:main 'hello-world.core
       :output-to "main.js"
       :optimizations :advanced
       :target :nodejs})

Comment: I was focused on using `lein run -m clojure.main node.clj` I get `Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate cljs/build/api__init.class or cljs/build/api.clj on classpath.`